# Can't execute rosjava Nodes. RosRUn not found Exception

Tags: rosrun, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I`ve been able to build and execute the tutorial_pubsub.
Then i created a new Rosjava package in an existing catkin_ws.
When i run gradle install and gradle installApp it all compiles right.
But when i now try to execute these new nodes:

```
scryer@Scryer:~/catkin_ws/src/rosjava_foo$ ./build/install/rosjava_foo/bin/rosjava_foo ben.dude.Listener
```

i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ros/RosRun
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ros.RosRun
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.ros.RosRun. Program will exit.
```

What am i missing to execute Nodes that are not in the rosjava folder?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101691/can%27t-execute-rosjava-nodes.-rosrun-not-found-exception/) by [Scryer](https://answers.ros.org/users/8846/scryer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have the rosjava workspace sourced? RosRun is a class inside rosjava, and the script that you are running will assume you already have that class in your classpath.

If you installed rosjava from source, source the `setup.bash` file of its respective environment before trying to run your own node. That should work.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0